# Passing data out of a Alamofire function into a global variable in a swift playground

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift-playground

I'm trying to use alamofire to work with an api on a website. And so far, ive gotten it to give a response, but whenever I do, I keep getting a scope error.

Here is the code. I'm trying to get "response" out of there and into a variable

```
AF.request("\(website)/favorites.json", method: .get, headers: headers).responseString { response in
    debugPrint("\(response)")
}
```

After the function, I tried putting `print(response)` after the function so it looked like this:

```
AF.request("\(website)/favorites.json", method: .get, headers: headers).responseString { response in
    debugPrint("\(response)")
}
print(response)
```

But I get this error:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:30:7: error: cannot find 'response' in scope
print(response)
      ^~~~~~~~
```

How do I pass the response out of the function.

Comment: The function works asynchronously, what's wrong to proceed inside the closure? Or use a completion handler as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function). And I'm sure the next major update of AF will support `async/await`

Comment: `response` exists only between `{ response in` and `}`, not outside, that's the "scope". Now, managing asynchrone is a other concept, see the linked question in the previous comment.